# How to solve VBA Paste formula error 1004 and subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to paste below formula in excel but it shows

> error 1004

Actual Formula:

```
="Fixed Text: Fixed Text="""&C3&""", Fixed Text="""&D3&""", Fixed Text="&E3&", Fixed Text="&F3&", Fixed Text="&", Fixed Text, Fixed Text="&I3&", Fixed Text="&J3&", Fixed Text"""&K3&""";{"&A3&"}"
```

Tried VBA Code:

```
Worksheets (" Fixed Text").Range (A2).Formula="=CHR(34)Fixed Text: Fixed Text=CHR(34)CHR(34)CHR(34)&C3&CHR(34)CHR(34)CHR(34), Fixed Text=CHR(34)CHR(34)CHR(34)&D3&CHR(34)CHR(34)CHR(34), Fixed Text=CHR(34)&E3&CHR(34), Fixed Text=CHR(34)&F3&CHR(34), Fixed Text=CHR(34)&CHR(34), Fixed Text, Fixed Text=CHR(34)&I3&CHR(34), Fixed Text=CHR(34)&J3&CHR(34), Fixed TextCHR(34)CHR(34)CHR(34)&K3&CHR(34)CHR(34)CHR(34);{CHR(34)&A3&CHR(34)}CHR(34)"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you make a question there should be a minimum content as input, expected output, what did you try, what did you research and where are you stuck in... Which one is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Simple procedure to implement formula is as below.

1. Copy formula from cell and paste it in VBA Editor window.

   `ActiveCell.Formula = =A1&""`
2. Select formula text and perform FIND (") & REPLACE ("").

   `ActiveCell.Formula = =A1&""""`

[image]

3. Wrap it with "" finally

   `ActiveCell.Formula = "=A1&"""""`

I had written a code for doing this step which is posted on Chandoo Org forums. Link is provided below.

https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/copy-formula-from-excel-to-clipboard-in-vba-compatible-format.35997/