# Recieving type mismatch error on sumifs in vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

The following code works fine when typed into excel manually:

```
Range("O7").Formula = "=IFERROR(SUMIFS(Data_Table[Hours],Data_Table[Date]," > "&[@[Start Date]],Data_Table[Date]," < "&[@[End Date]]),"")"
```

However when doing it in VBA, I receive the type 13 vba error, I'm not sure why?

This should just sum the hours, as long as it is between the start and end date

Comment: Double the quotes inside the string

Comment: This is how i type into VBA `"=IFERROR(SUMIFS(Data_Table[Hours],Data_Table[Date]," > "&[@[Start Date]],Data_Table[Date]," < "&[@[End Date]]),"""")"` Above is what I would type into excel

Comment: It should work right?

Comment: You missed some quotes around the `<`

Comment: Even this site's formatting is showing you that the `>` and `<` don't fall within quotes as you currently have them.

Comment: You can refer link here for an easy step by step procedure in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59692159/8759927) which should help!